# Получить значение из динамических input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть функция строящая таблицу.
Данная функция вызывается при загрузке страницы

```
var strResult = "";

$.each(contacts, function (index, contact) {
    strResult += "<div class=\"row\">";
    strResult += "<input class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.ID + "\"/><input id=\"first_name+" + contact.ContactID + "\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.first_name + "\"/>;
    strResult += "<button name=\"del=" + contact.ContactID + "\"  data-action=\"Delete\" class=\"btn btn-default btnDel\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></button>";
    strResult += "</div>"
});

$("#divResult").html(strResult);
```

И кнопка, клик которой обрабатывается здесь

```
$('body').on('click', '.btnsv', function () {
    var id = CutId(this.name); // обрезка id имя кнопки
    var contact = // здесь хочется, чтобы данные из input first_name + contactID записывались сюда

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:55285/api/values/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(contact),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) { },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

```
$('#first_name+' + id).val() // не работает
```

Comment: `не работает.` в чем конкретно выражается? Ошибки какие-то выдает или начинает бегать в трусах по дому и кричать - помогите насилуют?

Comment: пишет что переменная undefined.

Comment: ну посмотрите почему ваша `CutId` ничего не возвращает....

Comment: функция CutId возвращает значение. Она просто здесь не представлена.

Comment: Вы уверены? аналогичный код работает https://jsfiddle.net/g82v3ywp/1/    т.е. айди скорее всего не возвращается а дальше и не может ничего найти

Comment: Да в методе CutId тоже используется split и алерт после функции выводит нужный id. Возможно ли, что проблема в том что функция которая рисует таблицу вызывается ajax когда document.ready. И jquery просто не видит эти id? вот функция https://jsfiddle.net/54fp2f1g/

Comment: Странное дело. Когда из <input id=\"first_name+" + contact.ContactID + "\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.first_name + "\"/> в id "first_name+" был убран + то все заработало. Стало id "first_name"

Comment: недопустимый символ в идентификаторе. я даже не заметил его) на автомате правильно пишу, лол

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, оформи свои комментарии в виде ответа :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id=\"first_name+" + contact.ContactID + "\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.first_name + "\"/>
```

В данной строке в id=\"first_name+" стоит недопустимый символ в идентификаторе, правильно вот так.

```
 <input id=\"first_name" + contact.ContactID + "\" class=\"form-control\" value=\"" + contact.first_name + "\"/>
```

спасибо [Алексей Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)